# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:validateExternalOverrideSigning'

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-import, external-dependencies, caldroid

I am using caldroid library for calendar activity and It works fine.

But I needed to change it's style.

So I added caldroid library(directory) under the application like this.

[image]

and I changed my dependencies

> dependencies {
>      ...
>       compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:2.3.1'
>      ...
>   }

to

> dependencies {
>      ...
>       compile project(':libraries:caldroid')
>      ...
>   }

Then, It works fine under the debug mode.

But I can't generate signed APK because of this message.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:validateExternalOverrideSigning'.
>   Keystore file /Users/xxxxxxx.android.keystore not found for signing config 'externalOverride'.

Is there any solution about this error?

Answer (score 7):

I had this same problem here. The point is that when you created your KeyStore, Android Studio sent it to another place, different from the path of your app. Probably she was saved in

```
suaHome/documents/android-studio/bin
```

Just search it in this place and ready. Everything is solved. Tip: never miss this KeyStore view after you publish your APP with it. I have helped.

Answer (score 5):

I find android studio -> Build -> Generate Signed APK -> Next -> key store path(if you Create new..  then it will be a key name only, SO to fix it(Choose existing),then key store path will be on Absolute address. In end it will be OK.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX Sierra (v10.12.3), Android Studio (v2.3) create the KeyStore in:

```
Macinthosh HD/Applications/Android Studio/Contents/bin
```

Move the KeyStore in your app directory, and you can create APK

Answer (score 0):

As of Studio 2.3.3 by default, it creates the file under `Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\`.